# xamarin forms listview height

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, expandablelistview

всем доброго времени суток, есть проблема с версткой, есть listview,  в нем несколько expander, все работает отлично, но expander при открытии отображается только на высоту страницы телефона, все что ниже не отображается вовсе, сталкивался кто то с подобным?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App7.MainPage">
    <ListView x:Name="mainListView" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Expander>
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding title}"/>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Text="Переиминовать группу"/>
                                        <Button Text="Удалить из шаблонов"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding exp2s}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <ViewCell.View>
                                                <Frame Padding="0">
                                                    <Expander Tapped="Expander_Tapped">
                                                        <Expander.Header>
                                                            <StackLayout>
                                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                    <StackLayout>
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding task}"/>
                                                                        <Label Text="Ответсвенный:"/>
                                                                        <Label Text="Контрольная дата:"/>
                                                                        <Label Text="Особый статус:"/>
                                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                                    <StackLayout>
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding taskResult}"/>
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding otvetstvenniy}"/>
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding contrData}"/>
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding status}"/>
                                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                                </StackLayout>
                                                                <Label Text="Что сделать"/>
                                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                    <Label Text="{Binding chtoSdelat}" MaxLines="{Binding maxlines}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                                                                    <Label Text=">"/>
                                                                </StackLayout>
                                                            </StackLayout>
                                                        </Expander.Header>
                                                        <StackLayout>
                                                            <Label Text="Комментарий:"/>
                                                            <Label Text="5000 строк"/>
                                                            <Label Text="Напоминание"/>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Expander>
                                                </Frame>
                                            </ViewCell.View>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </Expander>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: на жёлтом фоне видно что элемент не закончен, но дальше контент не отображается]

Comment: в данный момент исправил, обернув главный frame в scrollview, пока что исход всех устраивает, но все же хотелось бы знать можно сделать элемент listview больше экрана

Answer (score 1):

ListView и ScrollView вместе использовать не стоит, они оба поддерживают прокрутку. нужно использовать либо ListView, либо ScrollView. вложенные StackLayout с различными Orientation нужно заменить на Grid, это повысит быстродействие и упростит схему. Grid сложнее понять, чем StackLayout, и многие его недооценивают, но в данном случае Grid подходит лучше. expander-ы можно заменить на IsVisible. чем проще структура, тем легче с ней работать.